# shared pointer and raw pointer lifetime

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, lifetime, temporary

Could someone explain simply the reason why this does not work:

```
std::shared_pointer<Bar> getSharedPointer() {
    return std::make_shared<Bar>();
}

...

auto foo = getSharedPointer().get();
```

Apparently using the raw pointer `foo` will cause a segfault because the lifetime of the shared pointer returned by `getSharedPointer()` will have run out. Somehow I would expect it to last until the end of its scope (like whatever block it is inside).

Is this correct and are there any analogous examples to this situation?

Comment: Can't find `getSharedPointer` documented in the standard library or common third parties. No clue what happens. Recommend adding a bit more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `getSharedPointer().get();`, `getSharedPointer()` returns a temporary `std::shared_ptr` which will be destroyed after the expression immediately, and the pointer managed by it will be deleted too. After that `foo` will become dangled, any dereference on it causes UB.

```
auto foo = getSharedPointer().get();
// foo have become dangled from here
```

You could use a named variable instead:

```
auto spb = getSharedPointer();
auto foo = spb.get();
// It's fine to use foo now, but still need to note its lifetime
// because spb will be destroyed when get out of its scope
// and the pointer being managed will be deleted too
```

Comment: please, add a note that `spb` will only last until end of scope

Answer (score 2):

```
auto foo = getSharedPointer().get();
```

Whenever a function returns a type that is not a reference, the result of calling the function is an rvalue. Also, because the function `getSharedPointer()` returns a class type, the result is a temporary object.

The lifetime of that temporary object is defined as the end of the evaluation of the outermost expression, here `getSharedPointer().get()`. As soon as the `foo` variable is initialized, the owning smart pointer is destroyed; when the last `shared_ptr` owning that object is destroyed, the object is deleted.

Here `getSharedPointer()` always returns `shared_ptr` that doesn't share the managed object (`use_count()` is 1), so when that copy of the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed, the object is destroyed and the pointer to the object is invalid.

(I am not sure why you are returning a `shared_ptr` and not a `unique_ptr` here.)

The proper use of a smart pointer, or any class that "owns" (controls the lifetime of) other resources (resources that you are still allowed to access directly), is to keep the "smart" pointer/owner alive as long as you need to access the ressource.

So the "smart" pointer (owning object) needs to be named. Also, I am not sure that you really would want to hide the fact that it is a smart pointer from the view of the reader with `auto`.

```
std::shared_pointer<Bar> foo = getSharedPointer();
// use foo.get()
```

You may want to hide the exact type of managed object:

```
std::shared_pointer<auto> foo = getSharedPointer();
```

Comment: ill have to refer to the code again to see if a unique ptr makes more sense in the app, but thanks for the heads up; ill check it out. also, you explained exactly what i needed to know about temporary objects and lifetimes, which ive failed to educate myself about due being new-ish with cpp. thanks.